# Pyinstaller y docxtpl creo un archivo.docx pero me dice que la dirrecion es invalida

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, python-docx

Quiero crear un documento baso en un template con la libreria docxtpl y me funciona cuando lo compilo directamente en `python3 menu.py` pero quiero dejarlo como ejecutable el problema creo que es con pyinstaller porque incluyo los datos que necesito en .spec pero el problema es que cuando intentento crear el documento me da un error y me dice que no exite el path y obvio no existe puesto que apenas se creara el documento en la carpeta el problema es con la linea

```
#irrelevant code.
FinalDocxPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), loadpath('DocxSaveDocument'))
ColoscopiaTemplateDoc.render(contex)
ColoscopiaTemplateDoc.save(f"{FinalDocxPath}/{filename}ReporteColposcopico.docx")
DBpath =os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), loadpath('DatabasePath'))
```

la funcion `loadpath('DocxSaveDocument')` lo unico que hace es extraer el valor de un diccionario donde esta el path de donde quiero que se guarde pero ya intente hacerlo sin eso y es el mismo error el error me lo arroja directamente en la terminal

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
  File "screenColoscopia.py", line 65, in submission
  File "docCreate.py", line 72, in createDocument
  File "docxtpl/template.py", line 753, in save
  File "docx/document.py", line 135, in save
  File "docx/parts/document.py", line 111, in save
  File "docx/opc/package.py", line 172, in save
  File "docx/opc/pkgwriter.py", line 32, in write
  File "docx/opc/phys_pkg.py", line 141, in __init__
  File "zipfile/__init__.py", line 1320, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/19/hdb9pg_n4rg2mrsn8fmg4dd00000gn/T/_MEInjTllr/documents/pacientes/AlexisReporteColposcopico.docx'
```

yo creo que el problema es que intenta cargar directamente el documento antes de que se ejute la funcion `.docxsave('directorio')` en el error pues el nombre del documento es el que yo le orotogo por default.

Comment: Justo me choqué con esto hace una semana. La variable `__file__`, en el exe, apunta a un directorio de archivos temporales creado por los exes de pyinstaller. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53511380/12913664). Si lees los comentarios en dicha respuesta, la mejor solución resulta ser usar `sys.argv[0]` en lugar de `__file__`

Comment: @DanteS. Muchas gracias cambie el codigo y use `sys.argv[0]` y resulto que si funciono lo testie una vez y no funcionaba resulto que tenia la carpeta en el directorio bien y ya funciono, muchas gracias